# Invoking a function on a "side" of a Bifunctor dependent on the value of a boolean

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

If I have an instance of `Bifunctor[A,A]` bf, a function `f : A => A` and a `Boolean` value `p`:

```
def calc[A, F[_,_]: Bifunctor](p: Boolean, bf: F[A, A], f: A => A): F[A, A] = {
  val BF = implicitly[Bifunctor[F]]
  BF.bimap(bf, (a : A) => if (p) f(a) else a, (a : A) => if (!p) f(a) else a)
}
```

How can I put this more concisely (and expressively)? Basically I am trying to invoke a function on a side of a *bifunctor* (e.g. a `Tuple2`) dependent on some predicate. If the predicate is true, I want to map the LHS and the RHS if it's false

```
val t2 = (1, 2)
def add4 = (_ : Int) + 4
calc(true, t2, add4) //should be (5,2)
calc(false, t2, add4) //should be (1,6)
```

---

*Given that I want to use tuples (as opposed to the more general `Bifunctor`),I seem to be able to use **[arrows](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/example/ExampleArrow.scala.html)** as follows*:

```
def calc[A](p: Boolean, bf: (A, A), f: A => A): (A, A) 
  = (if (p) f.first[A] else f.second[A]) apply bf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all that much nicer:

```
def calc[A, F[_,_]:Bifunctor](p: Boolean, bf: F[A, A], f: A => A): F[A, A] =
   (if (p) (bf :-> (_: A => A)) else ((_:A => A) <-: bf))(f)
```

A little nicer:

```
def cond[A:Zero](b: Boolean, a: A) = if (b) a else mzero

def calc[A, F[_,_]:Bifunctor](p: Boolean, bf: F[A, A], f: Endo[A]): F[A, A] =
  cond(p, f) <-: bf :-> cond(!p, f)
```

Some Haskell, just for the language envy:

```
calc p = if p then first else second
```

Comment: The trouble is that I'm writing this *inline* (i.e. I don't want to declare an extra method), so I don't want to have to write `bf` twice, because it is (in fact) the result of a method invocation. The arrows solution I found actually works really well

Comment: I should say that I also want to only access `p` once as well

Comment: For the haskell solution, do you not need to apply the result to the bifunctor? Or is that implicit? (I don't know haskell)

Comment: The type of calc is: `(Bifunctor f) => forAll a. Bool -> (a -> a) -> f a a -> f a a`. So you could say `(if p then first else second) f bf`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: fixed to return `(A,A)` instead of `A`

Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't this what temporary variables are for?  With a regular Scala tuple:

```
Some(bf).map(x => if (p) x.copy(_1 = f(x._1)) else x.copy(_2 = f(x._2))).get
```

or

```
{ val (l,r) = bf; if (p) (f(l),r) else (l,f(r)) }
```

Comment: Can you do that with arbitrary bifunctors?

Comment: @Apocalisp - Probably not (I haven't had an occasion to use arbitrary bifunctors so I'm not well-versed in their properties), but I was going off of the "given that I want to use tuples" part of the question.

Comment: Fair enough. Bifunctors just have one method `def bimap[A, B, C, D](k: F[A, B], f: A => C, g: B => D): F[C, D]`, satisfying some obvious laws (given by parametricity).

Comment: Rex - this doesn't answer the question - notice that the method should return an `F[A,A]` - yours just returns `A`. But the temporary variables scoped to the call-site only is a nice touch

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - Whoops.  Fixed.  @Apocalisp - Adopting this with a general bifunctor would be too ugly to bother with.

Answer (score 0):

Does this variation on [Apocalisp's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156262/invoking-a-function-on-a-side-of-a-bifunctor-dependent-on-the-value-of-a-boolea/4157638#4157638) work?

```
def calc[A, F[_,_]:Bifunctor](p: Boolean, bf: F[A, A], f: A => A): F[A, A] =
   (if (p) ((_: F[A,A]) :-> f) else (f <-: (_: F[A,A])))(bf)
```

*Note: I didn't test this with scalaz.*